# Filter df based on multiple column values of other columns in the same df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have df below:

```
id | status | id_reference
1    True        NaN
4    False       1
2    False       Nan
7    False       3
6    True        2
10   True        4
```

How can I only filter or want the rows in the df, where:

the ***status column*** is ***True*** and the ***id_reference*** column value exists in another row in the df as a value in the ***id column*** as a value.

So based on above df,

I would want rows below:

```
id | status | id_reference 
6    True        2
10   True        4
```

actual df is much larger as this is a sample

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `id_reference` to `float` if you haven't already and use `isin`:

```
print (df.loc[df["status"]&df["id_reference"].astype(float).isin(df["id"])])

   id  status id_reference
4   6    True            2
5  10    True            4
```

Comment: Another time, when a user edits their questions such that the edit invalidates an answer, please rollback the question edit. If you're the only person to answer, you can choose to allow the question edit and modify your answer, but with multiple answers to the question which are invalidated by the edit, it really is best to proactively rollback the question edit. Please see [How much change to the question is too much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290297/3773011). Doing such rollbacks is something which it's intended be done by any user with full edit privileges (i.e. >2k reputation).

Comment: In addition to rolling back the question, I've rolled-back your answer to the version which was answering the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can try:

```
df.loc[df["status"] & df["id_ref"].isin(df["id"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = df.query('status == True & id_reference.notnull()')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def filterDataSet(self,dataSetValues):
    try :
        print(dataSetValues)  dataSetValues= dataSetValues.fillna(0)
        dataSetValues = dataSetValues[dataSetValues.id_reference>0]
        dataSetValues = dataSetValues[dataSetValues.status == True]
        return dataSetValues
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Exception while filter data ", ve)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, shortly prior to you answering the question, the question was edited by the question author in a way which invalidated the already existing answers. Making such an edit is [against policy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290297). I've rolled-back the question to the version which was answered by the other answers. Unfortunately, that means your answer is answering something different than the question now says. I don't have a perfect solution for the situation. That a rollback to the question would harm your answer was considered when choosing to go ahead [continued]

Comment: [continued] with rolling back the question, but there were three other answers (one you can't see because it's deleted) which were affected. Basically, the decision came down to should the harm to 3 answers be left, or rollback the question edit and harm 1 answer, yours. My choice was that it was better to have the harm be to one rather than three. I wish there was a better solution to this, but there really isn't one that I see. You can choose to do as you want with your answer. Some possibilities are to edit your answer to answer the question as it currently stands, delete your answer, etc.